# How to dynamically track changes to an `Association`

Tags: bugs, dynamic, associations

**Bug introduced in 10.4 or earlier and persisting through 11.1.1**

> CASE:3892974
>
> Thanks for bringing this to our attention. A report has been filed with the developers.

---

I can track changes to a list with `Dynamic` without too much difficulty

```
foolist = {};
Dynamic[foolist]
```

And if I were to append an element to `foolist`, the dynamic expression will refresh to `{list}`

```
AppendTo[foolist, list]
```

But when I do the same with an association,

```
foobar = <||>;
Dynamic[foobar]
```

And add a new entry to it

```
AssociateTo[foobar, foo->bar]
```

The dynamic expression won't be able to capture the change. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I don't think you do anything wrong, unless I'm missing something I think you should report this. p.s. notice that you can still do `AppendTo[foobar, foo -> bar]` and it will work well.

Comment: @Kuba Ah thanks! And it seems that all `Set` assignments to an association can be tracked as well

Comment: Indeed. I've reported that, will let you know in case of any news. (CASE:3892974)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meanwhile you can use:

```
AppendTo[foobar, foo->bar]
```

or more functional style:

```
foobar = <|foobar, foo->bar|>;
```

```
foobar = Append[foobar, foo->bar];
```

Comment: Won't the result of the "more idiomatic" be an undesirable `<|<||>, foo->bar|>`?

Comment: @LLlAMnYP I don't understand, have you tried? But maybe I shoud've said "more functional style".

Comment: since it's the weekend, no, I haven't. Are you saying, the first element won't be the empty association that foobar was before assignment? Since for, say, a list saying `foobar={}; foobar={foobar, foo->bar}` will give `{{}, foo->bar}` and not `{foo->bar}`

Comment: @LLlAMnYP `<|assoc1, assoc2|>` works like `Merge[{assoc1, assoc2}, Last]`

Comment: Interesting, so it autoflattens.